# I found some code relating to if else, and tried changing syntax, but it didn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

UPDATE:

Thanks to everybody's wonderful input, I now have the code working properly in the main page.  Still can't figure out why that same code isn't functioning in the widget.  it's pulling down the title and permalink, so I know it's getting the data, but the custom values are returning as zero

I am making a wordpress page in which the group using the page is accepting challenges from viewers.

The challenges page is a special template that shows a percentage bar of how complete the challenge is.

the bar was working OK, with a small glitch in chrome, but the client wanted 'pending' for challenges that had 0% completeion and 'completed' for 100% instead of the graph.

I've put this code into both the page and a widget with strange results.  on the page, only the percentage bar ever shows, but on the widget, all challenges are listed as 'pending'

my code for the page is as follows:

```
<?php

/**
* Template Name: Challenges Page
*/

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- content -->
<div id="content">
    <?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'challenges', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $more = 0; ?>

    <div class="post archive">
        <div class="post-comments"><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?></div>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <?php       
        $target = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'target', true);             
        $complete = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'complete', true);     

        $percentage = $complete / $target;
        $percentage = round($percentage * 100);
        $whatsleft = 100-$percentage;
        if($whatsleft < 0) $whatsleft=0;

        echo "<table width='250' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr>";
        if($complete == $target) {
            echo "<td><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/completed.gif' style='width:200>px;height:24px;'></td>";
        } else if ($complete == 0) {
            echo "<td><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/pending.gif' style='width:200>px;height:24px;'></td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/themes/spectre/images/brown/grnbar.jpg' style='width:". $percentage ."px;height:12px;'></td><td><img src='http://www.smokeyvstheworld.com/wp-content/themes/spectre/images/brown/grybar.jpg' style='width:". $whatsleft ."px;height:12px;'></td>";
        }

        echo "</tr><tr><td colspan='2'><div align='right'>". $complete ." of ". $target ." completed</div></td></tr></table>";                      

?>

<div class="post-date"><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?></div>

<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_image_value', true)) { ?><div class="post-tnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_image_value', true) && $mb_resize == 0) { ?><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_image_value", $single = true); ?>&amp;w=98&amp;h=98&amp;zc=1&amp;q=95" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><?php } else if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_image_value', true) && $mb_resize == 1) { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "post_image_value", $single = true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><?php } ?></a></div><?php } ?>
<?php the_excerpt() ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="more">Continue reading...</a></p>                      
                    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

<div id="sidebar"><?php get_sidebar(); ?></div>    

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm confused as to WHAT I'm doing wrong, and why the same code works in one instance and not the other... I've tried switching from brackets to colons and back, etc.

Comment: can you format your codes first ?

Comment: You've posted a huge amount of code. I've just tried to format it as best I can, but make sure you only include the part of the code that's actually relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`width:200>px;height:24px;` => `width:200px;height:24px;`

Comment: That was definitely an error, but even with that fixed, the if and elseif aren't getting parsed into the page

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        $target = (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'target', true);             
        $complete = (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'complete', true);
```

Comment: `echo "</tr><tr><td colspan='2'><div align='right'>". $complete ." of ". $target ." completed</div></td></tr></table>";`
What is the output?

Comment: the output shows the valus of the custom fields in the page, but nothing in the widget.  it's showing correct percentage on the bar as well, (except in chrome)

Comment: You got 0 for completed and 0 form target. Do you used the right meta name (complete, target). Can you show some code, where the original green bars working, and get_post_meta executing?

Comment: that's in the widget.  The code on the left side of the page is showing bars, with the right numbers for the same challenge, but it won't show the 'pending' or 'completed'

Comment: Try the_ID() instaed of $post->ID.

Comment: didn't break anything, but no change in output, either

Comment: Ok. I don't know, I don't have more idea. :(

Comment: but strange... in the widget, when I did that, I got the numbers 210210 to the right of my first title...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing both the `==` to `===` so:

```
if($complete === $target) {
```

and

```
} else if ($complete === 0) {
```

Edit:
Thinking about it, the $complete value is probably a string so if above doesn't work change that line to

```
} else if ($complete === "0") {
```

Comment: Tried that..  I even tried switching what variables I'm using, so that if percentage is <1

Comment: Are you sure the meta values are correct? Is $post filled with the post you're expect it to be? please do a var_dump on $post to see if it's the correct post.

Comment: Actually, it fixed most things, and I was able to get it working in the post (not yet in the widget, but THANKS!!"